# ASP.NET MembershipProvider Exception when Adding user with Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have changed my Application Services Database to store membership things into my web site database.
After that, when I want to add User with the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool, I get the following exception:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   System.Web.Administration.WebAdminMembershipProvider.CallWebAdminMembershipProviderHelperMethodOutParams(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes) at
>   System.Web.Administration.WebAdminMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String
>   username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion,
>   String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser() at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs
>   e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.WizardChildTable.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

How can I fix this?
By the way, I've added a foreign key in my aspnet_user to point to my UserProperties Table.
Maybe I broke something by doing this?
And I can add roles without any trouble!

Comment: If I had to guess, you're probably getting a foreign key violation in SQL Server.

Comment: If you remove the foreign key, does your error go away?

Comment: In your exception it looks like it is calling a method via reflection. Can you check the exception to see if there is an inner exception?  The inner exception might have more meaningful information.

Comment: It works when I remove the link to my UserProperties table ! what's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have  passwordFormat="Encrypted" then you MUST have machineKey.

```
<machineKey    validationKey= "*****YOUR_VALIDATION_KEY*****"
decryptionKey= "*****YOUR_VALIDATION_DECRYPTIONKEY*****"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"/>
```

This is where I generated my machineKey:

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Answer (score 1):

FYI

I had the exact same error, and it turned out to be because I changed setting for password retrieval in the web config of my app.

I got this exception while settings were :

enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
passwordFormat="Encrypted"

Changing these back to default solved the problem/